# Cannot display Checkbox in using FXML in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I am using JavaFX to create a GUI application. 
I am working with Intellij and an using the SceneBuilder.

Here is my code to display a screen which has a CheckBox among other components.

When I try to run this application, it does not display the Ballot Box of the CheckBox, however, it does display it in the Scene Builder.

What property am I missing?

EDIT: Attempt to isolate the check boxes into a column of its own in the GridPane (no luck!) It still does not display the ballot boxes.

Comment: Your text field and your check box are in the same cell in the grid...

Comment: Yes, that is a requirement. Is that it?  I also tried doing an experiment where the CheckBox was the sole element on a screen, and it still did not display it.

Comment: I suspect that is the problem. If you put two nodes in the same cell they will be superimposed on top of each other. Which one you see (and whether you see all of each node) will depend on the space allocated to the cell (which ultimately depends on the size of the window, among other factors). But it doesn't really make any sense to put them in the same cell: put the check box in a new column and set the column span of other nodes to get the layout you are looking for. As for displaying *just* a checkbox and it not showing up... create a [MCVE] for that. You have something wrong somewhere.

Comment: I tried isolating the checkboxes in columns of its own, but I am facing the same problem. Just out of curiosity, could this be an Intellij-related issue? The Scene Builder happens to display the correct layout, but running the application creates this problem. This has led me to doubt if this was a problem with the IDE that I am using. I could be wrong.

Comment: I would think that would cause you to suspect that the IDE was the problem, not doubt that it was the problem. But what happens if you run it from the command line? And again, post a [MCVE]. No-one can really help if you don't post complete code.